# How to trim .mov without losing quality?

Tags: video, quicktime

When a video file (.mov recorded on iPhone) of resolution 1080x1920 is trimmed in QuickTime and saved as 1080p, the saved video resolution is 607x1024.

Is there a way to trim video and keep the original video resolution?

*p.s. QuickTime Version 10.1 (501.22) on Lion*

Answer (score 1):

Just trim your video on the iPhone, in your "camera roll". This is the only way I know won't  re-encoding the video.

Comment: Seems dumb, but this is actually the easiest—and seemingly the *only* —solution.